# How to change rejectExecution value to True in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I was looking into the Throttler in Apache Camel, reading on http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html it says the rejectExecution value is by default set to false.

My question is how do I change this value to true?

for instance in the route below, where would I change the default value?

```
from("direct:start")
 .throttle(5).timePeriodMillis(2000)
 .to("mock:throttled")
 .end()
.to("mock:after")
```

Comment: You should try a bit yourself, as its easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your Java editor, and press control + space to get a list of possible methods, and you can find it

```
from("direct:start")
 .throttle(5).timePeriodMillis(2000).rejectExecution(true)
 .to("mock:throttled")
 .end()
.to("mock:after")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i also wanted to know when this reject execution exception is thrown, does it discard the request coming in or or does it carry on processing the request when the throttle rate drops?

Comment: If true its rejected, by throwing an exception, then you can use Camel error handler to deal what to do. eg in this example whatever called the direct:start endpoint gets an exeption. If false, then it waits until the throttler is "free" and process the message later.

Comment: in camel is it possible to do something like, if  throttle exceeds 5 in 2000 milliseconds then I want to do a system.out letting me know the throttle has exceeded?